# Bash Password Special Character Checker

Tags: bash, passwords

So basically im trying to make my password validator check my password to see that it contains exactly one and only one of the special character (@$#!*&)

So far I got it so that it can identify if there is no special character in the parameters which is below, but i cannot seem to figure out how to make a statement that would make it so that it can identify that their is only one special character in the password.

```
if [ `echo $password | grep -c -E "[@#$%&*+-=]+"` -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: could you post some examples for valid passwords.

Comment: some valid passwords would be As1Bsaew$, as1H4bast@, Hu1@bastu
basically contains atleast 1 number, 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, and only one special character as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that there is *one and only one* character from the group `@#$%&*+-=`, run:

```
p=${password//[^@#$%&*+=-]/}; [ "${#p}" -eq 1 ] || echo "Error"
```

Note that in the regex `[^@#$%&*+=-]`, the place in which the `-` appears is important.  It must be either the first character (after the `^`) or the last character.  If it is in the middle, it would be interpreted as indicating a range of characters.

Alternatively, to verify that there is *one or more* of those characters:

```
[ "${password//[^@#$%&*+=-]/}" ] || echo "Error"
```

As for the other tests that you mentioned in the comments:

1. To verify that there is at least one lower case letter:

   ```
   [ "${password}" = "${password^^}" ] && echo "Error"
   ```

   `${password^^}` converts all the characters to upper case.  If this leaves `password` unchanged, then there were no lower-case letters and `Error` is displayed.
2. To verify that there is at least one upper case letter:

   ```
   [ "${password}" = "${password,,}" ] && echo "Error"
   ```

   `${password,,}` converts all characters to lower case.  If this leaves `password` unchanged, then there were no upper case characters and `Error` is displayed.
3. To verify that there is at least one number:

   ```
   [ "${password//[^0-9]/}" ] || echo "Error"
   ```

   `${password//[^0-9]/}` removes all non-numbers from `password`.  If there are no characters left after this, then `Error` is displayed.

All these tests are based on `bash` parameter expansions.